how to correctly interpret this WAVEFORMATEX from decompiled raw bytes?
I am working on an old (1999~) win32 decompiled game codebase.
In it, there is the following sequence of bytes, which were directly taken from the disassembled binary:
static char source_pcm_format[50] =
{
    2, 0, 1, 0, 34, 86, 0, 0, 147, 43, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 32, 0, 244, 3, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 255, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 192, 0, 64, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 204, 1, 48, 255, 136, 1, 24, 255
};

These bytes are passed into the function acmStreamOpen, casted to a LPWAVEFORMATEX:
mmresult = acmStreamOpen(&hACMStream, hACMDriver, (LPWAVEFORMATEX)source_pcm_format, &pcm_format, 0, 0, 0, 0);

this function call works correctly
When interpreting these bytes myself as a WAVEFORMATEX, the wFormatTag equals 2, which corresponds to ADPCMWAVEFORMAT.
When I interpret the bytes as a ADPCMWAVEFORMAT, things go weird:

The ADPCMWAVEFORAMT needs wNumCoefs amount of ADPCMCOEFSET.
50 bytes however are too few to store 256 coefficients.
When printing the coefficients the following way (I assume its MS-ADPCM):
ADPCMWAVEFORMAT* adpcmfmt = calloc(1, sizeof(ADPCMWAVEFORMAT) + sizeof(ADPCMCOEFSET) * 7); // MS-ADPCM
char source_pcm_format[50] = {
    2, 0, 1, 0, 34, 86, 0, 0, 147, 43, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 32, 0, 244, 3, 7, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 255, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 192, 0, 64, 0, 240, 0, 0, 0, 204, 1, 48, 255, 136, 1, 24, 255
};
memcpy(adpcmfmt, source_pcm_format, sizeof(source_pcm_format));
fprintf(stderr, "\n");
for(int i =0; i < 7; ++i) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%d %d\n", adpcmfmt->aCoef[i].iCoef1, adpcmfmt->aCoef[i].iCoef2);
}
fflush(stderr);

I receive the following output:

0 512
-256 0
0 192
64 240
0 460
-208 392
-232 0

This seems to be the coefficient list for MS-ADPCM, but shifted by a few bytes:

aCoeff = { {256, 0}, {512, -256}, {0,0}, {192,64}, {240,0}, {460, -208}, {392,-232} }

My goal is to correctly declare and transform the raw bytes into a ADPCMWAVEFORMAT (or WAVEFORMATEX).
I don't know why the code with the raw bytes works, when it seemingly contains invalid ADPCMWAVEFORMAT data.
Edit: sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) + sizeof(ADPCMCOEFSET * 7) returns 52.
So the bytes are 2 bytes less than what I would expect.
Did something get added between 1999 and today ?
wSamplesPerBlock seems to be the wNumCoefs amount, which is expected to be 7.

Whatever compiler/editor you're using is misinterpreting the structure. It seems to be using 16-bit packing whereas the actual structure definition is 8-bit packing.

I am using the default x86 compiler flags (no /Zp specified)

What does your compiler think sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) and sizeof(ADPCMWAVEFORMAT) are? These should be 18 and 22 respectively.

@Luke you seem to be right. on my end, sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX) is returning 20. But how exactly do I ensure the size is correct? This is a Win32 struct, so I can't add #pragma pack

user @cremno correctly identified the issue.
windows.h needs to be the first header to be included to ensure the struct alignment is properly set up for the struct definition of  WAVEFORMATEX.
This is the correct header order:
// header order important here
// clang-format off
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmreg.h>
#include <mmiscapi.h>
#include <MSAcm.h>
// clang-format on

This lets me create a proper ADPCMWAVEFORMAT variable like so:
ADPCMWAVEFORMAT* adpcmfmt = calloc(1, sizeof(ADPCMWAVEFORMAT) + sizeof(ADPCMCOEFSET) * 7); // MS-ADPCM
adpcmfmt->wfx.nSamplesPerSec = 22050;
adpcmfmt->wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = 11155;
adpcmfmt->wfx.nBlockAlign = 512;
adpcmfmt->wfx.wBitsPerSample = 4;
adpcmfmt->wfx.cbSize = 32;
adpcmfmt->wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_ADPCM;
adpcmfmt->wfx.nChannels = 1;
adpcmfmt->wNumCoef = 7;
adpcmfmt->wSamplesPerBlock = adpcmfmt->wfx.nBlockAlign * 2 / adpcmfmt->wfx.nChannels - 12;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[0].iCoef1 = 256;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[0].iCoef2 = 0;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[1].iCoef1 = 512;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[1].iCoef2 = -256;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[2].iCoef1 = 0;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[2].iCoef2 = 0;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[3].iCoef1 = 192;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[3].iCoef2 = 64;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[4].iCoef1 = 240;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[4].iCoef2 = 0;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[5].iCoef1 = 460;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[5].iCoef2 = -208;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[6].iCoef1 = 392;
adpcmfmt->aCoef[6].iCoef2 = -232;
MMRESULT mmresult = acmStreamOpen(&hACMStream, NULL, (LPWAVEFORMATEX)adpcmfmt, &fmt, 0, 0, 0, 0);

